# Word for applying liquid to a cloth

Tags: single-word-requests

I've just been putting protective oil on a wooden door using a cloth and was getting the oil onto the cloth using the technique of blocking the tin with the cloth and upending the tin so that a small amount of oil is left on the cloth.

I've used this technique all my life for various things but have never known a word or phrase to describe the action. I also use it when cleaning things with white-spirit or similar. When I had a toothache as a child, my mother used to apply Oil of Cloves to the tooth from her finger-tip using a similar action.

I'm fairly certain we don't have a word in British English, so I'd be really interested if there's a word in use elsewhere in the English-speaking world - or if any other language has a word that we can purloin.

If no-one has anything - let's make one up!

Comment: A verb for applying some fluid to a cleaning cloth by pressing the cloth up against the container's opening and then upending the container. Let's resurrect *tipple*.  *Tipple some cleaning fluid onto a clean rag.*

Comment: I like that! You should add that as an answer.

Comment: okeydokey, lefty.

Comment: @TRomano As a frequentative of *tip,* the word *tipple* can mean to 'tilt,' and that's the closest it comes to the OP's sense of tilting the tin (for whatever purpose.) The more common (primary?) meaning of *tipple,* however, is unrelated to this context.

Comment: @Kris, as we (facetiously) say in the States, "Tell me something I don't already know". :-)

Comment: **Tip** a small amount of oil onto a cloth.

Comment: This is not the site to ask for neologisms.

Comment: tipple means 'drink' which isn't the best idea for cleaning fluid.

Answer (score 6):

*moisten*, *dampen*, *wet*, *soak* apply depending on how much moisture is applied.

Comment: Certainly any of these are better than *tipple*, which has certain unattractive connotations.

Comment: For me, none of these fit the bill. They describe the state of dampness of the _cloth_ after the upending has been performed - not the process of achieving that state. The technique is fairly specific in the amount of fluid that it allows onto the cloth and it's virtually impossible to get it wrong by pouring too much. I think it demands its own verb.

Comment: @Lefty These words are verbs. These are not to be confused with moist, damp, wet, or soaked as adjectives.

Comment: Moisten is my vote.

Answer (score 1):

A verb for applying some fluid to a cleaning cloth by pressing the cloth up against the container's opening and then upending the container. Let's resurrect *tipple*. *Tipple some cleaning fluid onto a clean rag.*

Just don't tipple the cleaning fluid!  It's a phrasal verb: "tipple...onto".

Comment: Please try to provide a definitive source supporting the answer. Also, it helps if some use-case sentences can be included for completeness.

Comment: Sorry, I see no evidence for this definition in OED, and I've never come across it before. You say *"Let's **resurrect** this word"* - I say *"Show some evidence it was **ever** used in this sense"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think this is an attempted extension of meaning -- pl. see my comment under the question above.

Comment: This would be a bad choice because *tipple* has the literal meaning of drinking, and I don't think you wish to suggest drinking potentially harmful chemicals, even filtered through a cloth.

Comment: Resurrect, as in revive the obsolete transitive verb *tipple* (to throw or pitch something) and combine it with the sense of being upended in the obsolete intransitive verb (cf. *topple* over) and combine it also with the "consume|use strong fluids" meaning of the verb "tipple" :-)

Comment: @Robusto: I am in all things Darwinian, but we could include a picture of "Mr Yuk" on the label.

Comment: @Kris: clearly, I'm taking the OP up on his challenge "let's make one up!".

Comment: @Kris: Yeah - I'd already taken note of the comments. But despite OP's *"Let's make one up!"*, I'm not sure I accept that a proposed "neologistic definition" is a valid response here. And I'd be against ***tipple*** anyway, for the same reason as Robusto,

Comment: For what it's worth, I'll add my thoughts to this. If we are going to make-up a new word (or a new usage), it might be worth steering away from a word that confuses with drinking - although it is a pretty unlikely set of circumstances that would see someone drinking the cleaning fluid. When I suggested that @TRomano submit it as an answer, I took the use of the word "resurrect" to mean "re-purpose" rather than "revive a previous usage".

Answer (score 1):

I think the verb you are looking for this action is: ***to dab***.

> To cover lightly with or as if with a moist substance: *dabbed the back of the fabric with glue.*
>
> <sub>[[The American Heritage Dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=dab)]</sub>

Some Examples from Google and Google Books:

> If you're a shower person, **dab some oil on a scrap of cloth** and hang it from the shower to release the aroma.
>
> [Kitchen Witch's Guide to Magickal Tools *By Patricia Telesco*]
>
> ---
>
> Remove the scope from your rifle. **Dab some water on a soft cloth**. Wipe the outside of the lenses clean with the cloth.
>
> http://www.ehow.com/how_7412240_repair-scratches-rifle-scopes.html
>
> ---
>
> All you need to do is **dab some oil on a cotton ball or pad** and swipe across your face to remove makeup for a natural makeup remover solution.
>
> http://www.onegreenplanet.org/lifestyle/diy-olive-oil-based-skincare-products/
>
> ---
>
> Protect your hand with a grill mitt, **dab some oil on a cloth**, and quickly but efficiently wipe down the hot grills.
>
> http://www.mrtimes.com/opinion/editorial/five-golden-rules-bring-best-food-to-table-1.580563

Comment: I have sometimes seen "dab" used as the action of getting fluid onto a cloth - but genuinely don't know whether they mean to use this technique or to pour some liquid into a vessel and then "dab" the cloth into that pool of liquid. I hope you can see that the 2 things are not the same and it would be helpful to have a distinction. I also have a feeling that this use of "dab" may be slightly more common in the US than in the UK.

Comment: @Lefty: This is the word for this technique. Another example: you can dab some makeup remover on a cotton pad and wipe your face. You can do a search on Google and see similar examples.

Comment: @Lefty: Added more examples to prove it is the right verb. I don't know why I got the downvote though. Maybe it is not used in all English speaking countries (though I doubt because it is a very basic verb) but definitely used in North America.

Comment: @ermanem Again, your examples are ones where I would NOT naturally assume you get the fluid onto the cloth by this process. To me, I "dab" a cloth or sponge INTO a fluid which is in a shallow dish. I might then "dab" the cloth/sponge ONTO something - which implies a lighter touch than wiping or rubbing. I appreciate that you may understand "dab" to mean this process but I don't. EDIT, sorry, I can see you are in US! BTW, the downvote was no from me.

Comment: @Lefty: These examples are not INTO. They are ON a something from a bottle or a container. Maybe it is used in other sense too, yes. I'm in Canada. "Dip" connotes INTO the liquid more than "dab".

Comment: Canada! Sorry again! Yes, in the UK, dab and dip are quite interchangeable in many contexts so there is definitely no way that dab is reserved exclusively for this use - and I would doubt that many British people would even use dab in this context. For example, there is a building technique called "dot and dab" which involves placing small "dots" of substance such as adhesive by "dabbing" onto a wall. We might also dab a wound to gently clean it without causing pain.

Comment: @Lefty: No need to be sorry. I didn't know that it isn't used in this sense in UK. Dab is not exclusively reserved for this use in North American English. But it is used for this action also and it is quite common.

Answer (score -1):

How about something with **"flip[ping]"** in it...

"the wig,""the lid," "the bird".... all already taken (too bad. 'cause "the lid" could have worked...

let's see...:

"flipping the cloth" maybe, or maybe "flipping the flop"?